# Can't save Woocommerce Authorize.net gateway settings

Tags: woocommerce, authorize.net

I have the Authorize.net Woocommerce extension. I have some old API settings in their. I was trying to update the settings, but everytime I click save, the page reloads and the old settings are back. Has anyone experience this problem? I can't find anymore information about it on their website or anywhere really.

I go to Settings -> Payment Gateways -> Authorize.

Change any of the settings on that page.

Click Save at the bottom.

Page reloads. Message appears saying that settings were saved, but old settings are still there. I check the database and the old settings are still there.

I am able to save other settings in wordpress, and other woocommerce settings, but not for Authorize.net gateway.

I have disabled and enabled the plugin again. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully saved my settings. Here's how I did it:

1. Disable & delete plugin (authorize payment gateway)
2. Delete row from database where info was stored (I found it by searching for the api login we use)
3. Re-upload plugin & enable
4. Re-input settings

Comment: Yeah. I can't test it anymore. But I'm glad you found a solution.